# Como eu faço uma form modificar as palavras?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu gostaria de colocar um texto em um `form` e ele transforma em um "link", por exemplo:

> login id 76561198281829407

Modificar para: https://steamcommunity.com/id/76561198281829407

Preciso de um exemplo do HTML e JS ou jQuery para isto.

Comment: Quais foram suas tentativas para solucionar o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o JQuery a seu favor. Tente o seguinte e veja se isto é o que você está procurando.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#inserir").click( () => {
    var link = $("#link").val();
    console.log(link)
    $("#linkuser").html("<a href='https://steamcommunity.com/id/"+link+"' target='_blank'>Link Steam</a>");

});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>     
        <title> ... </title>              
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:powderblue;">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <h2>  Digite seu ID:</h2>
        <input id="link" type="text" name="link" /> <br/>
        <input id="inserir" type="button" value="Enviar" />
        <div id="linkuser">
            
        </div>
    </body> 

</html>
```

Isto resolverá o seu problema, basta adequar ao seu código.